# Binary file pattern scanning and editing

Tags: c++

I want to make correct pattern scan and modify some bytes in a binary file with c++.
It will be an JPEG so file has to be not broken.
Must use pattern and mask system. Because some of bytes is unknown.

Here is the my example code:

```
 bool run(std::string fileName, std::vector<char> toSearch, std::vector<char> newData, char* mask) {

        // Open the file and check, if it could be opened
        if (std::fstream fs{ fileName, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out }; fs) {

            // Read byte by byte which will be really slow
            for (char c{}; fs.get(c); ) {

                // Check if we read a charcater that matches the first character of the search string
                if (c == toSearch.front()) {

                    // Remember the current position of the read file pointer (it is now one after the read character)
                    std::streamoff position = fs.tellg();

                    // Not try to match the rest of the search string
                    bool match{ true };
                   
                    // Go through the rest of the charcaters in the search data
                    for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < toSearch.size(); ++i) {
                        // Read next byte and compare
                        if (mask[i] != '?' and fs.get(c) and c != toSearch[i]) {
                            // If there is a mistmatch, then stop reading and comparing
                            match = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // If there was a complete match
                    if (match) {
                        std::cout << "Complete match. " << std::endl;
                        // Set the write pointer to the begin of the matching bytes
                        fs.seekp(position - 1);
                        // Write the new data
                        std::copy(newData.begin(), newData.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(fs));
                        fs.flush();
                    }
                    // Now, replacement done or not, set read pointer back to original position
                    fs.seekg(position);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if (GetLastError() == 32) {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
                run(fileName, toSearch, newData, mask);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

```
struct PatternMap
{
    char* old;
    char* bypass;
};
std::map<char*, PatternMap > PaternMap = {
    { ("xxx"), {("\0x90\0x90\0x90")  } },
    { ("x?x"), {("\0x90\0x00\0x90")  } }
};


int iCrc = 1;
        std::map<char*, PatternData>::iterator it;
        for (it = PatternMap.begin(); it != PatternMap.end(); it++)
        {
            std::cout << ("Pattern: ") << iCrc << "." << std::endl;

            std::cout << strlen(it->first) << std::endl;
            std::vector<char> oldDataVec(it->second.old, it->second.old + strlen(it->first));
            std::vector<char> newDataVec(it->second.new, it->second.new + strlen(it->first));
  
           run(filePath, oldDataVec, newDataVec, it->first);

            
            
            iCrc++;
        }
```

Its working well when mask is xxx
But when unknown byte appears ( just make ? the middle x as x?x) , its not working as expected.

Comment: Define "not working as expected".

Comment: @tadman Can not find the searched bytes for replacing

Comment: This is a ton of code to look through, and I have no idea where to even start looking for that problem. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @tadman Would you open an binary file from your computer with an HEX editor, and choose 5 bytes in the file. For example you choosed these bytes: 64 64 36 63 62 32 and defined filePath as the "C:\x.jpg". If you use xxxxxx as your mask, the code will find the choosed bytes and replace with your custom bytes. But when you use xx?xxx for mask, it getting fail to find these bytes.

Comment: @tadman Also i have to use "?" in my mask, because some bytes are changing depends to file. So code should work like that; compare bytes if you see "?" on the next mask char just ignore and skip the byte and compare next one .

Comment: @ArminMontigny You are right at all. I just wanted to modify and test your code for pattern mask system.  So run function is does not matters. But still idk what i missing about mask.

Comment: @ArminMontigny in my idea it had to skip if current mask char is unknown (?) and continue as matched to next char. I am reading and reading again the code and still cant understand why its returns marched = false about unknown char